# ios adding dropbox like app functionality in my own app

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, dropbox-api

I have a app, in which I want the user to allow to download pictures from its dropbox account.
I am familiar with downloading and displaying the files and folder. My problem is, I want to give the user folder like option to navigate in a table view, as we see in dropbox ios app and web interface. I am having trouble to how to handle view controllers, which view controller for main dropbbox interface, then when user clicks on an folder I want him to navigate to the contents of next folder, and having an option to come back, but there could be n number of levels it can go in downward. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:[UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: That i know, but how to create multiple views, inside a folder

Comment: multiple views inside a folder? I don't know what you mean. If you want to navigate (like dropbox app does) though file system's folders, you only have to push a tableview controller on the navigation controller for the current folder. If you select a folder (that is the row that represents a folder) you push another table view and so on. If you select a file, then you push a view to show that file. The rest of the work (backwards, reloads, load and unload views, etc.) is done by the navigation controller.

Comment: Sometimes the most difficult part is to take account of how easy it is.